# NHibernate and MS SQL function NEWSEQUENTIALID() to generate an ordered GUID

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I configure NHibernate 3.3.1 (or some other version) to allow Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 to generate the primary key value (guid that is ordered) for a table with data type uniqueidentifier and default constraint NEWSEQUENTIALID()?

My testing has shown that I can setup the Id (PK) mapping as GeneratedBy.Guid.Native() but this will call select newid() and will not use the function NEWSEQUENTIALID().

I could generate the ordered guid client side with Id mapping, GeneratedBy.GuidComb() but I am concerned about multiple threads within the same process generating the same GUID.

My application requires database replication across active/active data centers and I would like to use ordered guids generated at the MS SQL servers (several active data centers) as primary keys.

I see this article,

[Nhibernate Identity mapping when using "newsequentialid" in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733529/nhibernate-identity-mapping-when-using-newsequentialid-in-db),

but it seems to be missing the point with the answer that shows how to setup NHibernate to use an NHibernate generated GUId.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default I believe nhibernate uses a guid.comb strategy to generate guids which should be ordered.  They aren't as obvious as when generated by NEWSEQUENTIALID() but should still be ordered.

Check out the following article on this:

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/05/21/using-the-guid-comb-identifier-strategy.html

Comment: I could use Guid.Comb strategy but really would like to know if I can take advantage of the MS SQL function NEWSEQUENTIALID(). As of yet, I cannot find an answer to that question.

Comment: @codemech If you are unable to find this functionality native to nhibernate you may be able to just write your own generator class that calls newsequentialid().  http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/creating-a-custom-id-generator-for-nhibernate.aspx

Comment: I think your idea makes sense. Thanks.